# Torsion in families of elliptic curves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Suppose that $f : X \to T$ is a family of elliptic curves over a $1$-dimensional base, and that $\sigma : T \to X$ is a section.  For how many $t$ in the base do we expect $\sigma(t)$ to be $n$-torsion on $X_t$?  (And what properties of the family does this depend on?)

I am most interested in the case that $f$ is just a pencil of plane cubics, so that the base locus gives $9$ sections.  It seems to me that if we fix one of the sections as $0$, then another of the nine sections $\sigma$ becomes 2-torsion for exactly one value of $t \in T$.  (Because the line between the point $0$ and the point $\sigma$ is tangent to exactly one member of the pencil at $\sigma$.)  But for how many parameter values does this section $\sigma$ become $3$-torsion?

Comment: Do you have an example ? In characteristic not $2,3$ up to a $\overline{k}$-rational change of variable don't you have $a,b,x,y \in \overline{k}(t),  E/\overline{k}(t):Y^2=X^3+aX+b,4a^3+27b^2 \ne 0, (x,y) \in E(\overline{k}(t))$ and you are asking about the poles of  $\sigma_n=[n] (x,y) \in  \overline{k}(t)\times  \overline{k}(t)$ the  problem being when those poles $t_j$ are zeros or poles of $4a^3+27b^2$ ?

Comment: Take a general pencil of plane cubics.  The example is the second paragrph.